# Was bedeutet "gerne" nach einem Verb in der Befehlsform?

Tags: word-usage, adverb

Ich weiss schon, was "gerne" nach einem Verb im Indikativ bedeutet, aber was heisst es, wenn es nach einem Verb in der Befehlsform steht?

z.B.

> Ich esse gern Pizza = I like to eat pizza

aber

> Komm gerne vorbei, wenn du Zeit hast.

Übersetzt bedeutet der zweite Satz: "Come by, if you have time" aber wie sollte man *gerne* verstehen, und lässt es sich eigentlich übersetzen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Das ist in der Tat eine der merkwürdigeren Formulierungsweisen, der man vor allem in der Reklame bzw. im Dienstleistungssektor begegnet. 'Gerne' soll hier einfach nur betonen, dass man willkommen ist, das Angebotene in Anspruch zu nehmen. *'Kommen Sie gerne vorbei!', 'Fragen Sie gerne unsere Telefonberaterin!', 'Fordern Sie gerne unseren Katalog an!'* soll also die harsche Befehlsform in ein freundliches Angebot bzw. eine Einladung umwandeln.

Comment: "Du kannst mich gerne fragen, wenn Du etwas nicht verstehst" wäre werbefrei und auch kein abgemilderter Befehl.

Answer (score 9):

I'd translate

> Komm gerne vorbei, wenn du Zeit hast.

or the equivalent

> Du kannst gern vorbeikommen, wenn du Zeit hast.

by

> Feel free to visit me/us, if you have time.

Comment: +1: Imperative and indicative have no real difference in meaning here due to "gerne" which makes it voluntary either way.