# Gern im Marketingsprech

Tags: vocabulary, word-classes

In [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7017/was-bedeutet-gerne-nach-einem-verb-in-der-befehlsform) ging es bereits um die "Marketingsche" Verwendung gerns.

> Bei Fragen können sie uns gern anrufen.

Furchtbar. 
Was mich interessiert, ist die Frage, welche Funktion *gern* hier hat bzw. mit welcher Wortart (funktionell gesehen) wir es zu tun haben. Ist es ein Adverb? Wenn ja, worauf genau bezieht es sich (Verb, Kommentaradverb)? Dazu ein Test:

> Gern können sie uns bei Fragen anrufen.

Hat dieses *gern* die gleiche "Reichweite" wie das andere?

Oder sollte man *gern* im ersten Beispiel als eine Partikel auffassen? Dafür spräche, dass man es in einen Partikelcluster integrieren kann

> Das würde ich ja aber gern doch schon mal wissen.

EDIT:

Da die Partikel-Variante erstmal vom Tisch ist (siehe Antwort @Toscho) und das Modalverb die Sache erschwert, habe ich mich für diesen Satz entschieden.

> Rufen Sie gern an.

- Was für ein Adverb ist *gern* hier?
- Ist diese Verwedung nicht eigentlich semantisch falsch?

Comment: Vom Marketing willst Du Dich nicht lösen? Wir können das gerne im Chat diskutieren, und glaub mir, ich will Dir da nix verkaufen. Oder brauchst Du eine Waschmaschine? Ein iPhone? Vielleicht ein TV-Spülfilm-Abo? Was ich zeigen will: Mit `Du` statt `Sie` wird es gleich viel familiärer (jetzt aber weg!). ;)

Comment: @userunknown: Ne, ich würd mich davon nur ungern lösen, denn die sind es die es so falsch benutzen. Es gibt da schlimme schlimme Beispiele, die mir jetzt nicht einfallen wollen

Answer (score 1):

`gern` ist das Adverb zum Adjektiv `lieb`. Es fungiert in deinen Sätzen auch als Adverbial zum Prädikat `anrufen können`, egal wo es sich im Satz befindet. Die Frage nach dem Partikelcluster ist nicht aufschlussreich, weil an der Stelle eben auch Adverbien stehen können, z. B. `heute`.

> Das würde ich ja aber heute doch schon mal wissen.

Comment: Ok, also antwortet es auf die Frage "wie"? Richtig? Das heißt, ich kann nur anrufen wenn ich es "gern" tue. Oder zumindest, wenn ich es "gern" tue, dann kann ich anrufen, ob ich auch anrufen kann, wenn ich es nicht "gern" tue ist nichts gesagt.

Comment: So pauschal würde ich das nicht sehen. Du spielst mit der Frage `wie` anscheinend auf Modaladverbiale an. Die Unterteilung der Adverbiale und die Zuordnung eines solchen sind aber nur Modelle. Sprache ist flexibler.

Comment: Ja, darum geht es mir ja. Welche Adverbiale ist "gern" denn hier? Irgendeine Idee?

Comment: Aus der Liste in http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbiale_Bestimmung würde ich mich für Konditional- oder Instrumentaladverbial entscheiden.

Answer (score 1):

Ich sehe nicht, dass es im Marketing eine herausragende Rolle spielt. Das "gern" bedeutet nicht, dass der Anrufer es mit Freude soll, sondern dass der angerufene sich gern den Anrufen widmet.

> Sie können mich gern mal am Abend besuchen.

Ein Beispiel mit anderen Begriffen als "gern" will mir aber nicht einfallen, und eine Regel, aus der sich oben gesagtes ergibt, kann ich auch nicht nennen.

> Ich kann Ihnen das liebend gern einpacken.

... wäre eine ganz ähnliche Verwendung, bei der die Person, die es gern tut, noch deutlicher wird. Als Höflichkeitsfloskel taucht es aber wohl eher in werbenden Kontexten auf.

Vom Satzbau, das gebe ich zu, sieht es eher aus, als sei der andere der, der es gerne tut.

Comment: Das "kann" macht mir ein bisschen Probleme. Daher habe ich meine Frage editiert.